# OpenDKIM Sign envelope-from and header from in the same email

Tags: email, postfix-mta, dkim

i use OpenDKIM and Postfix. I need to sign the envelope-from and the header from in the same message.

When I send the message I only see that the email is signed with the domain header from and not with the envelope-from.
In the opendkim configuration I have added the `MultipleSignatures yes` variable but it doesn't work for me.

Here the config of OpenDKIM:

```
Mode    sv
Syslog  yes
SyslogSuccess   yes
LogWhy  yes
UserID  opendkim:opendkim
Socket  inet:8891@localhost
Umask   002
SendReports     yes
Canonicalization        relaxed/relaxed
Selector        default
MinimumKeyBits  1024
KeyFile /etc/opendkim/keys/default.private
KeyTable        /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable    refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts   refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
TemporaryDirectory      /var/tmp
OversignHeaders From,Sender
MultipleSignatures yes
```

SigningTable

```
*@mail01.domain1.com mail._domainkey.mail01.domain1.com
*@domain2.com dkim._domainkey.domain2.com
```

KeyTable

```
dkim._domainkey.domain2.com domain2.com:dkim:/etc/opendkim/keys/domain2.com/dkim.private

mail._domainkey.mail01.domain1.com mail01.domain1.com:mail:/etc/opendkim/keys/mail01.domain1.com/mail.private
```

Although the email is signed, I need it to be signed by the header from and the smtp.mailfrom too

```
smtp.mailfrom=mail01.domain1.com; live.com.ar; dkim=pass (signature was
verified) header.d=domain2.com;live.com.ar; dmarc=bestguesspass
action=none header.from=domain2.com;compauth=pass reason=109
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of mail01.domain1.com
designates 200.x.x.x as permitted sender)
```

Any ideas?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can include [SignHeaders (dataset)](http://www.opendkim.org/opendkim.conf.5.html) to your OpenDKIM config.

**SignHeaders (dataset)** - Specifies the set of header fields that should be included when generating signatures. If the list omits any header field that is mandated by the DKIM specification, those fields are implicitly added. By default, those fields listed in the DKIM specification as "SHOULD" be signed (RFC6376, Section 5.4) will be signed by the filter. See the OmitHeaders configuration option for more information about the format and interpretation of this field.

You must see this headers in **h** part in dkim section in your email header. This article explain more detials: [Explanation DKIM (DomainKeys Identified Mail) in all details](https://www.mybluelinux.com/explanation-dkim-domainkeys-identified-mail-in-all-details/)